# Name for person who uses epanorthosis

Tags: terminology, derivational-morphology, derivation

How would you from the noun *epanorthosis* derive a name describing a person who frequently uses this rhetorical tactic?

An *epanorthocian?* *Eparnorcian?* *Epanorthologist?* *Epanorthic?* Something else?

The word means the intentional immediate replacement of a word or phrase with a more correct or emphatic one.

Schoolbook example: "Thousands, no, millions!"

Geeky example: "Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman; he's visiting from corporate HQ." (Where ^H is the control code for Backspace.)

More: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/epanorthosis), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanorthosis)

Comment: Definitely not *-ologist* that would be one who studies e~.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is probably 'epanorthotist'. The precedent set by 'orthotist' is

> **orthotist**, *n.*
>   A person who makes or fits orthoses.

["orthotist, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/260953?redirectedFrom=orthotist (accessed February 27, 2016).]

The same agentive suffix suits 'epanorthosis', which derives from the compound of the prefix 'epana-' (itself a compound prefix deriving from the prepositions 'epi' and 'ana') and 'orthosis'.

> **epana-**, *prefix*
>   before stems beginning with a vowel *epan-*, a combination of two Greek prepositions ἐπ(ί) upon, in addition + ἀνά up, again, occurring in some rhetorical terms, adopted from Greek.
>   ....
>   **ˌepanorˈthosis**  *n.*  [Greek ὄρθωσις a setting straight, < ὀρθοῦν, < ὀρθός straight] a figure in which a word is recalled, in order to substitute a more correct or stronger term.

["epana-, prefix". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/63161?rskey=If9mbn&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed February 27, 2016).]

The straightforward noun by agentive suffixation might lose out in recognizability to the existing adjective-noun combinative possibility:

> epanorthotic rhetorician

(for the adjective 'epanorthotic', see the list of terms under 'epana-' from the work cited previously).

Comment: From *epanorthotic* one might also derive *epanorthoticist*